# Understanding mounting an executable on the host machine with Docker?

Tags: docker

I’m new to Docker and I have an odd case where I’d like to have a cpp executable(which creates a TCP Server) be located inside a RHEL 7 Docker container. This executable has a lot of run-time dependencies (Static libs and DLL).

I would like to do the work for setting up the dependencies just once, and then just redistribute the container to the team. Is it possible to have the executable live inside the Docker container (which will then be linked to the run-time dependencies that are in the container) but mount and run the executable on the host machine i.e., so the TCP server uses the host machine’s IP address and not the Docker container's IP address?

Again, the executable (The TCP Server) would have to be using the dependencies that are on the container while running on the host machine.

The host machine would be RHEL 7. ​

Update 1:

Sorry I forgot to add a key parameter. There will be files on the host machine that the server will need access to. I know you can mount directories to the container at startup, but the files that the server will need access to will be sub-directories that will be created on the fly. 
I.e., as requests come into the server, the server will need access to the directory /servers_important_files/. Sub-directories will be dynamically created under /servers_inportant_files/ that the serve will also need access to. Because of this, I was wondering if there was a way to run the executable on the host machine.

Thanks all!

Comment: Regardless of whether the executable is inside the Docker container or mounted from the host, if it is executed inside the container, then it will run in the context of the container.

Comment: Thanks for helping! So, you’re saying if I mount the executable from the container to the host machine, the executable will be, “running on the host machine” just like a natively installed executable would be, but will be using the containers run-time dependencies? These decencies would have been linked to the executable when I compiled the executable on the container before mounting it to the host machine and running it.  
Correct?

Comment: No, the opposite. It will run in the container. I don't really understand the use case, but I suspect it's because you want to be able to access the service from the host (or other hosts) in which case my answer below solves it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the server process to be available as something to connect to on the host (or from other hosts to your physical host), then you can bind the port.

E.g. (80 is the port on the host, 8080 is the port in the container). This also mounts a volume from the host to a location inside the container as requested in the edit.

```
docker run -p 80:8080 -v /dir/on/host:/dir/in/container nginx
```

In this scenario the dependencies and executable would all be inside the container.

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/

Comment: Sorry I just updated my questions. see update 1. If I bind the ports, and run the server on the container, can I mount the directory /servers_important_files/ in a way where it also will mount any sub-directories ( even if they don’t exist yet at the time of mounting /servers_important_files/ to the container\)?

Comment: If you mount a directory from the host into the container then it's contents will be "live" (for want of a better word) inside the container. So if you later (from the host) create some subdirectories inside the mounted directory, they will immediately be accessible inside the container.

Comment: Great! Thanks so much for the help. Binding the ports and running the server on the host container( and understanding how Docker handles mounting directories) answers my question.

Comment: I updated the answer to add a volume bind mount from the host to the container. This is by default read-write, but if you read the docs you can make it read-only.

Comment: No probs. You could mark as answered to close the loop.

Comment: That just means clicking the check mark that's next to your answer right? Sorry I'm color blind and new to using Stackoverflow. It's hard to see if the check mark is changing colors when I click it. Did I marked the question as answered? Thx.

Comment: Yeah. That's it! Thanks.